# Defining range according to changing cell

Tags: vba, excel

thx for all the help and advice:
The code i am working on, finds a cell with a certain value in a column. I want, when the macro goes back to the original sheet, that the code select a Range in order to copy and paste said range.
The range depends on the cell where it found the value earlier offset by (0, -1) and going to 8 columns to the right. for example: range("A1:A8").Select, when A2 is the cell with the specific value.

```
Dim r As Long 'Row number
            Dim c As Long 'Column number (A = 1, K = 11, etc.)
            r = Rng1.Row
            c = Rng1.Column
            With Sheets("Registro")
                .Range(.Cells(r, c - 1), .Cells(r, c + 8)).Cut
            End With
            With Sheets("Detaille Completo")
                NextFree = .Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1, 1).Row
                .Cells(NextFree, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End With
            Sheets("Registro").Select
```

Comment: Maybe to clarify. I was trying various methods that all didnt work out completly so this is just the basic code i have now.

Comment: The cell that contains the value was stored as Rng1 earlier.

Comment: Would you please more clearly state the issues and desire?  I've having some issues following the narrative.  You have a macro to find a value on a page; then "something" gets copied based on that found cell.  You then move back to a specific sheet (Registro) and paste the range.  I'm lost on the offset reference and I need to figure out what is "something."

Comment: @Cyril Yes of course. thx for the help. Its a rather complex code. It's for an inventory. The macro looks for the name: "jack" in the b column. It then adds some values to another sheet which works all fine. After that I want to go back to Registro and select the range, based on where we found "Jack" earlier, which is saved as Rng1. We then copy this range to another sheet and finally go back and delete the range.

Comment: This is the code i have now. I got rid of the original problem but the paste special is throwing an error now. Please help me with this mess.
`ActiveSheet.Range(Rng1.Offset(0, -1)).Offset(RowOffSet:=0, ColumnOffset:=9).Select
                        Selection.Copy
                        Sheets("Detaille Completo").Select
                        NextFree = ActiveSheet.Range("C8:C" & Rows.count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
                        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & NextFree).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Sheets("Registro").Select`

Comment: You need to save the location of where Jack was found.  That's the "something" I'm missing.  What is the total range you are looking to copy?  If you save the cell location .row and .column of Jack as x & y, and know you want the next 10 rows of data after Jack, you would have use .Range(.Cells(x+1,y),.Cells(x+10,y)) as the source data.  That's what we need to narrow down, what the source data is.  Rng1 helps me know where Jack is, so we can do an offset... but how many rows/columns are we offsetting?

Comment: @Cyril ` With Worksheets("Registro").Range("B:B")
        Set Rng1 = .Find(What:=FindString1, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)`

This is where i get the rng1 from. The total range i want to copy is, for example A1 to J1, when A2 is Jack. We need to first select the cell to the left of Jack(A2) and then go to 9 cells to the right.

Comment: It needs to be very clear when you're saying Columns and Rows... Left/Right would be columns, Up/Down would be rows, and references such as A1 to A8 (the post example) would be moving in one column (A) from row 1 to row 8.  In the above comment example, I can't marry up the words with what you've used thusfar.  That's where I was getting lost; I am unsure if this is different in other language versions of Excel.  I will try to give an answer as to what I believe I'm understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving this a whirl; breaking down your code first:

```
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + numval
Application.Goto (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Registro")) 'Will nix this
ActiveSheet.Range("Rng1").Select 'AVOID SELECT/ACTIVATE
Range(Rng.Offset(0, 1)).Offset(RowOffSet:=0, ColumnOffset:=9).Select 
Selection.Copy 'Activity on the above 3 lines... let's Cut so you don't have to delete later (if i understand below)
Sheets("Detaille Completo").Select 'sheet change
NextFree = ActiveSheet.Range("C8:C" & Rows.count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row 'finding empty cell
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & NextFree).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'pasting
Sheets("Registro").Select
Set kopieren = ActiveCell 'Looks like you're clearing the contents... will change copy to cut so you don't have to go back
kopieren.Resize(kopieren.Rows.count, _
    kopieren.Columns.count - 9).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 3).Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

Now to update:

```
Dim r as Long 'Row number
Dim c as Long 'Column number (A = 1, K = 11, etc.)
Dim j as Long 'Row of first available empty cell on Detaille Completo
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + numval
r = Rng1.Row
c = Rng1.Column
With Sheets("Registro")
    .Range( .Cells(r-1, c), .Cells(r+8, c+9).Cut 'Selected data is CUT from sheet
End With
With Sheets("Detaille Completo")
    j = 1
    Do until IsEmpty(.Cells(j,3).Value)
        j = j + 1
    Loop 
    .Cells(j, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Should only need first cell of range to paste
End With
```

Read the comments for details.

Comment: Chose to not use offset because I couldn't tell exactly how many rows/columns were needed to move from the initial cell.  Used .Cells and gave +/- to the value which should be easier to manipulate in the future as it's r for rows and c for column, allowing for easier understanding when asking questions.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :) I tweaked with the +- a bit. Now its all good. But the NextFree is throwing an error: No cells found. I don't know why that is.

Comment: @Newbie Should NextFree be the last row in the column?  If so, we can change the formula altogether, or if it need to be the first empty cell we could do a loop.

Comment: `With Sheets("Detaille Completo")  
                    NextFree = ActiveSheet.Range("C7:C" & Rows.count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row  
                    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & NextFree).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  
                End With  `

I think i fixed it this way. 
Now the Pastespecial has an error it says it can't execute.

Comment: @Newbie See updated code... looks like you've got things out of order:   NextFree = .Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1,1).Row

Comment: Sorry I am so bad at this. I really appreciate your help. It still gives me the error, even with your improved code.

Comment: The paste special method of the range object cannot be executed.

Comment: @Newbie gdi... that's my bad... xlPasteValues; updated in the code

Comment: I updated my question so you can see the code as i have it now.  It still throws the same error message as before.

Comment: @Newbie Try now; I got rid of the NextFree and put in a Do Until loop.  This should record a row that can be used to paste.

Comment: you are a master of your trade. Thanks very much it finally worked I had to tweak it here and there and now it finally works thanks to your help. It does exactly what i want it to:):):). Should i post it as a new answer or just as a comment?

Comment: @Newbie Accepting this answer is sufficient; the comments help dictate the rest.  Glad it all worked out for you!